# PyCharm debugger doesn't step into a statement that throws

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Basically the issue is that I can't step into a part of the code:

[image]

The method seems to be correctly resolved, but when I step into it, instead of ending up inside the method, the `validate` throws an error and I end up in the `except` branch:

[image]

Comment: will link it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-71393/PyCharm-debugger-doesnt-step-into-a-statement-that-throws